# SGEN doesn't work after upgrading from VS2012 to VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sgen

When I compile my c# solution under VS2013 (Version 12.0.21005.1 REL) it cannot build part of projects with error message:

*Error  32  The command "“C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sgen.exe”  /a:"Project.dll" /f /v" exited with code 3.   Project*

Post build event: “$(FrameworkSDKDir)\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sgen.exe”  /a:"$(TargetPath)" /f /v

Indeed, folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools" doesn't exists: "\Bin" contains folder "NETFX 4.5.1 Tools" only.

Target framework of project: ".NET Framework 4".

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools registry keys, I think.  *Very* unhealthy, sounds like you had a preview installed and not properly uninstalled.

Comment: it didn't solve my issue: Error 64 The command "“C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sgen.exe”  /a:"project.dll" /f" exited with code 3. project

Comment: You have the screwed-up machine, it thus makes sense for **you** to search the registry for "netfx 4.0 tools".

Comment: if removing/installing VS2013 will solve the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

solution (by Microsoft):

> It is best practice to use the **$(SDK40ToolsPath)** property to get the
>   .NET SDK binaries path rather than manually building the path with the
>   $(FrameworkSDKDir) property. Using **“$(SDK40ToolsPath)sgen.exe”** should
>   work in Visual Studio 2013 and earlier versions.

[$(FrameworkSDKDir) value in VS macros (post build event) references invalid path](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811986/-frameworksdkdir-value-in-vs-macros-post-build-event-references-invalid-path)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error today. The project I am working on is currently being maintained in VS2012. On my new install, I have VS2013 (installed first) and VS2012. I got this error building in VS2013.

The problem was the folder where sgen.exe was being run from doesn't exist on my machine. On my machine, I have `$(FrameworkSDKDir)\Bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\` but not `$(FrameworkSDKDir)\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\` folder.

To resolve the issue, I created a NETFX 4.0 Tools\ in the parent source control director and checked it in. This way, the reference is no longer dependant on each user's machine. My post build is now `"$SolutionDir\..\..\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sgen.exe" /force "$(TargetPath)"`

Comment: Ok, I understand the workaround. But I want to know if VS2013 has bug and, probably, Microsoft released or is going to release patch?

Comment: I am not sure this is a bug. The problem seems to be that our solutions are dependant on a specific folder name outside of the solution directory. Any dependency outside of source control is going to risk being at least somewhat brittle. The best change I could hope for from MS would be a checkbox on build properties for "After Build, Generate XML serialization assembly"

Comment: In case it matters in your research about the issue in VS2013, I experienced it in Premium v12.0.21005.1 REL